# Using a JavaFX TextArea, how to increase fontsize without increasing scrollbar size?

Tags: javafx, textarea, scrollbar

How can I increase the fontsize in a JavaFX TextArea without increasing the size of the scrollbar?

The following example shows an enormous scrollbar. I would like it to remain the normal scrollbar size

```
public class TextAreaProblem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea(text);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        textArea.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 50");

        Scene scene = new Scene(textArea, 400, 400);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



    String text = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a full understanding of why this is, but if you set the font size in `em` it works without affecting the size of the scroll bar:

```
textArea.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 4em;");
```

For a (partial) explanation, the default stylesheet modena.css has the following comment:

> ### RESIZING FOR DIFFERENT SCREEN DPI
>
> When the screen DPI changes Windows will use a different font size by
>   default.  The default is 12px and can change to 15px or 18px depending
>   on user  preference or screen DPI. On Mac the default is 13px and
>   embedded will depend  on hardware. To make UI controls scale and be
>   the right proportions for each of  these font sizes we base the
>   padding (which controls size of control) on the  font size. This is
>   done using the CSS measurement unit of a "em" where (1em = font size).

The size of the scrollbar is controlled by specifying padding in `em`, for example the default stylesheet contains:

```css
.scroll-bar:vertical > .increment-button > .increment-arrow {
    -fx-padding: 0.167em 0.333em 0.167em 0.333em; /* 2 4 2 4 */
    -fx-shape: "M7.071,1L8.5,1.002L4.5,4l-4-2.998L1.93,1L4.5,2.976L7.071,1z";
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box , -fx-shadow-highlight-color, 1, 0.0 , 0, 1.4);
}
```

So what I *think* is happening is that when you specify the font size in pixels for the text area with

```
textArea.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 50");
```

you change the definition of `1em` for the text area to be `1em=50px`, making the scroll bar button have padding of approximately 17 pixels high and 33 pixels wide. My guess is that specifying the font size in `em` just scales the size of the font but doesn't change the definition of `em` (you could hardly define `1em=4em`...), so doing it this way doesn't affect the size of the scroll bar.